# AWS: Ruby describe_instance_type_offerings() gives exception: "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I used this reference: [AWS SDK for Ruby: `describe_instance_type_offerings()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_instance_type_offerings-instance_method)

When I try to implement this, it gives an exception:

> `Undefined method`

Please guide me.

```rb
client = Aws::EC2::Client.new
resp = client.describe_instance_type_offerings(
    {
        dry_run: false,
        location_type: "region",
        filters: [
            {
                name: "location",
                values: ["us-east-1"],
            },
        ],
        max_results: 1,
        next_token: "NextToken",
    }
)
```

Comment: For a start, you should not be providing `next_token` in an initial call. This is used for paginated results, where there is another page of results available (indicated by a non-Null value for `NextToken` in the response).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  after removing  next_token . still getting same issue.

Comment: `Undefined Method` suggests that it does not know what command you are calling. Please make sure you are using the latest version of the AWS SDK for Ruby, because this command was added relatively recently.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks , i'll sure check it . is my filteres value is right in my question ,as in document it's not clear .

Comment: Yes, I managed to run the same command using Python, using the same values (as long as the command is being run against the named region). I'd say it's your SDK version for sure.

Comment: Thanks ! i updated library , and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the latest version of the AWS SDK for Ruby, because this command was added relatively recently.

While the APIs are backwards-compatible, the library will need to be updated to access the newer functions and capabilities.